# Angular2 RC2: The application cookie is not set even with withCredentials true

Tags: cookies, angular

I am trying to do CORS with Angular2. I followed the solutions by workarounds by extending the browserXHR and setting the withCredentials. This sets the cookie in the response XHR but not the cookies in the resources tab of the browser.
I was excited about RC2 that had the withCredentials flag might solve my problem, but no success. I used the Angular2 example and put something like bellow in my boot.ts:

```
   import { HTTP_PROVIDERS, BaseRequestOptions, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';



class MyOptions extends BaseRequestOptions {
    withCredentials = true;
  }


export function main() {
  return bootstrap(AppComponent,
    [HTTP_PROVIDERS, {provide: RequestOptions, useClass: MyOptions} /* provide(BrowserXhr, { useClass: CORSBrowserXHR })
    ]);
```

This does the same thing (cookies in the response but no cookies in the browser's cookies) to be used for the authentications.

I might be wrong but I thought that the browser's cookies will be set by the browser after you set the withCredentials flag to true. 
I am really out of my element and just started learning web development with Angular2, so please let me know if I my understanding is totally wrong and I am missing a critical point.

Thanks,

Afi

Comment: same problem here. I use Django-Rest-Framework with a login post call